# Rotation vector layer feature in OpenLayer3

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

Is possible in OpenLayers3 rotate a feature in editing mode like in old OpenLayers2?

At the moment I found only the possibility to modify, draw and drag features but not rotate.

Thanks in advance for reply.

Answer (score 0):

You can rotate a feature styled with `ol.style.Circle`, `ol.style.Icon`, `ol.style.Image` and `ol.style.Text`.

You can use [`setRotation(rotation)`](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.6.0/apidoc/ol.style.Icon.html#setRotation) on an icon.

Here is [an example](http://plnkr.co/edit/PoEXSr?p=preview), click on the marker to rotate it.

Comment: Thanks Jonatas, but I must rotate the geometry of the feature, line or polygon. Have you any idea about it?